# Using matplotlib to print to exact physical dimensions

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinate-transformation

I am using Python to design objects and I want to print their plans to an exact scale.

Suppose I have a square of size 3.0 in data coordinates which I want to print to a square of exactly 100mm.

At present I plot this, save to a PDF file, print it out and measure the actual length of the sides: If this is 50mm, say, then I reprint it using 200% scaling in the printer interface.

How can I use matplotlib to ensure that the actual printed size of the output comes out at 100mm in the first place (with the default 100% printer scale)?

Answer (score 0):

I found most of what needed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400116/using-matplotlib-how-can-i-print-something-actual-size).  This prints 1 unit as 1.0cm, so to print 3.0 as 10cm the axis limits just needed to be scaled by a further 0.3.