# Is there an easy way to print a Matplotlib figure (Saros Dial) to an exact size on a DIN A4 jpeg?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, printing

As part of a COVID/Lockdown/Geek project making a 3D Antikythera model I need to print a Saros Dial to be exactly 8.9 cm in width. I have muddled my way through playing around with the print scale. This works for the office printer. However I want to have it etched on plexiglas and I need to upload a DIN A4 jpeg or pdf with the (0,0) coordinate right in the centre [image]

Code for the dial below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


# define parameters
a = 2 # determines the width of the turns - set to 1 means width is 2 Pi
thetaMin, thetaMax = 26*np.pi, 34*np.pi # Dial starts at the 13th turn and finishes at the 17th turn
steps = 223+1 # Number of Saros periods (+1 for end marker)


# Generate plotting values
# Main spiral

theta = np.linspace(thetaMin, thetaMax, steps)

r = theta * a

x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(-theta)

# Main spiral outer rim completion
thetaMinComp, thetaMaxComp = thetaMax, thetaMax+(2*np.pi)

thetaComp= np.linspace(thetaMinComp, thetaMaxComp,steps)


rComp = thetaComp * a

xComp = rComp*np.cos(thetaComp)
yComp = rComp*np.sin(-thetaComp)

# Seperator lines 
# Need to plot between the period startpoint accros the turn(out from the center (0,0))
l=np.sqrt(np.square(x)+np.square(y)+1.2) # calculate length from center, just shortening it makes it not overshoot
xnew= x*1/l*(l+2*np.pi*a) # get the x  for the line extendeaccros the turn
ynew= y*1/l*(l+2*np.pi*a) # get the y  for the line extendeaccros the turn

#start plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))

plt.axis('off')

for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot([x[i],xnew[i]],[y[i],ynew[i]], c='r', lw=2)
#     plt.scatter(x[i], y[i], c = 'g') # Plots dial points for reference

steps = 223+1 # Number of Saros periods (+1 for end marker)
a = 2 # determines the width of the turns - set to 1 means width is 2 Pi
thetaMin, thetaMax = (26*np.pi+(2*np.pi)/(.5*steps)), (34*np.pi+(2*np.pi)/(.5*steps)) # Dial starts at the 13th turn and finishes at the 17th turn


theta = np.linspace(thetaMin, thetaMax, steps)

r = theta * a

xx = r*np.cos(theta)
yy = r*np.sin(-theta)
xxnew= xx*1/l*(l+2*np.pi*(a*.5)) # get the x  for the line extendeaccros the turn
yynew= yy*1/l*(l+2*np.pi*(a*.5)) # get the y  for the line extendeaccros the turn
plt.plot(x, y, c='r', lw=2)
plt.plot(xComp, yComp,c='r', lw=2)


plt.scatter(0,0)

plt.text(0,75,'Saros Dial', {'fontname': 'Herculanum',
                         'fontsize': '100',
        'fontweight' : 'bold',
        'verticalalignment': 'baseline',
        'horizontalalignment': 'center'})

plt.show()
```

I have found [Using matplotlib, how can I print something "actual size"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400116/using-matplotlib-how-can-i-print-something-actual-size) but is still fiddling. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Did you try increasing your `dpi` and save that as `PDF`. It worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This proved to be frustrating. It is printer dependent...and online printer specifications for the margins may not match the actual margins when printing. I have a hunch it may even be OS or driver specific.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# This example fits DIN A4 paper on a HP Laserjet Pro 200 MFP

# figure settings

left_margin = 0.2
right_margin = 0.9
top_margin = 0.6
bottom_margin = 0.6 


left_right_margin = left_margin+right_margin
top_bottom_margin = top_margin+bottom_margin
figure_width = 21-left_right_margin # cm
figure_height = 29.7-top_bottom_margin 

# Don't change
left   = left_right_margin / figure_width # Percentage from height
bottom = top_bottom_margin / figure_height # Percentage from height
width  = 1 - left*2
height = 1 - bottom*2
cm2inch = 1/2.54 # inch per cm
h_corr = 1.017
v_corr = 1.011

# specifying the width and the height of the box in inches
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(figure_width*cm2inch*h_corr,figure_height*cm2inch*v_corr))

ax = fig.add_axes((left, bottom, width, height))

# limits settings (important)
# plt.xlim(0, figure_width * width)#(0,0) at left bottom
# plt.ylim(0, figure_height * height)#(0,0) at left bottom
plt.xlim(-figure_width * width/2, figure_width * width/2) #centers (0,0)
plt.ylim(-figure_height * height/2, figure_height * height/2)#centers (0,0)


# your Plot (consider above limits)
# # define parameters
a = .03538 # determines the width of the turns - set to 1 means width is 2 Pi
thetaMin, thetaMax = 26*np.pi, 34*np.pi # Dial starts at the 13th turn and finishes at the 17th turn
steps = 223+1 # Number of Saros periods (+1 for end marker)


# Generate plotting values
# Main spiral

theta = np.linspace(thetaMin, thetaMax, steps)

r = theta * a

x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(-theta)

# Main spiral outer rim completion
thetaMinComp, thetaMaxComp = thetaMax, thetaMax+(2*np.pi)

thetaComp= np.linspace(thetaMinComp, thetaMaxComp,steps)


rComp = thetaComp * a

xComp = rComp*np.cos(thetaComp)
yComp = rComp*np.sin(-thetaComp)

# Seperator lines 
# Need to plot between the period startpoint accros the turn(out from the center (0,0))
l=np.sqrt(np.square(x)+np.square(y)+1.2) # calculate length from center, just shortening it makes it not overshoot
xnew= x*1/l*(l+2*np.pi*a) # get the x  for the line extendeaccros the turn
ynew= y*1/l*(l+2*np.pi*a) # get the y  for the line extendeaccros the turn


for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot([x[i],xnew[i]],[y[i],ynew[i]], c='r', lw=1)


xx = r*np.cos(theta)
yy = r*np.sin(-theta)
xxnew= xx*1/l*(l+2*np.pi*(a*.5)) # get the x  for the line extendeaccros the turn
yynew= yy*1/l*(l+2*np.pi*(a*.5)) # get the y  for the line extendeaccros the turn
plt.plot(x, y, c='b', lw=1)
plt.plot(xComp, yComp,c='g', lw=1)
plt.scatter(0,0)


plt.text(0,4.75,'Saros Dial', 
         {'fontname': 'Herculanum',
        'fontsize': '30',
        'fontweight' : 'bold',
        'verticalalignment': 'baseline',
        'horizontalalignment': 'center'})


plt.plot([-8,-8],[-10,10])
plt.text(-7,0, ' 20 centimeters' , rotation=90, ha='center', va='center', fontsize=30, color='magenta')
plt.show()

plt.show()

# save figure ( printing png file had better resolution, pdf was lighter and better on screen)
fig.savefig('A4_grid_cm.png', dpi=1000)
fig.savefig('tA4_grid_cm.pdf')
```

[image: Saros Dial printed to exact size on DIN A4]